# Loopback 4 MySQL not allowing to manually create data for id column if generated is true

Tags: mysql, primary-key, loopback4, generated

I am using Loopback 4 first time and using MySQL as DB connector. I am able to use models with all my code but faced issue for id columns with `generated: true`.

First using `required: true` in my models is  not allowing to add data using API Calls.It giving me issue `id can't be blank`. I able to ignore this error if I made `required: false` That actually not a big issue as I expecting MySQL to generate value using AUTO INCREMENT.

But now I need to generate some fixture data using a single API. In that case, I need to manually insert data into `id` column something like

```
await this.projectRepository.create({
    id: 1,
    title: "My Project"
    createdAt: (new Date).toISOString()
});


await this.projectItemsRepository.create({
    id: 1,
    projectId: 1,
    title: "My Item 1"
    createdAt: (new Date).toISOString()
});


await this.projectItemsRepository.create({
    id: 2,
    projectId: 1,
    title: "My Item 2"
    createdAt: (new Date).toISOString()
});
```

So Project Id is foreign key in projectitems model. Now if I execute this script, I am getting issue for id  `id can't be set`.  Look like  loopback 4 blocking attempt to set value in case of id column is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First using `required: true` in my models is not allowing to add data using API Calls.

This is expected as this parameter is taken from the OpenAPI 3.0 spec, which works from the perspective of the API consumer (i.e. the API consumer MUST provide the parameter, not necessarily the ORM).

> So Project Id is foreign key in projectitems model. Now if I execute this script, I am getting issue for id `id can't be set`.

Set the Model configuration `settings.forceId: false`:

```js
@model({
  settings: {
    forceId: false,
  }
})
class MyModel extends Entity {/* ... */}
```

References:

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model#supported-entries-of-model-definition ([Git permalink](https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/blob/de84a35886fe747a7513e63f0415ae5d695e0c20/docs/site/Model.md#supported-entries-of-model-definition))

Comment: Okay, I was searching in field ( id ) properties for any solution, but you are correct `forceId` on model level is done the work. Thanks.